# How can I use cURL to download a list of URLs from a text file and change the file name?

Tags: macos, shell, curl, terminal, scripting

I have a list URLs in a file called urls.txt. Each line contains a single URL. (see example below)

```
https://website.com/media/r/x/3/rx34aw3/normal.jpg
https://website.com/media/q/3/c/q3cciw3/normal.jpg
https://website.com/media/f/7/e/f7eciw3/normal.jpg
```

Each URL leads to an image file. (normal.jpg) I want to download all of the image files using cURL and have each of the files have a separate name.

The following works but because each of the images is named the same (normal.jpg) when they are downloaded each one overwrite the previous.

```
xargs -n 1 curl -O < urls.txt
```

***Short-Term Workaround:*** I would like to append a number to the current name so when they are downloaded each one does not overwrite the previous.

*Would download as:*

```
normal01.jpg
normal02.jpg
normal03.jpg
```

***Long Term Solution:*** I would like to use a separate name in the file after the URL to name each of the images.

```
https://website.com/media/r/x/3/rx34aw3/normal.jpg 2435955711
https://website.com/media/q/3/c/q3cciw3/normal.jpg 2445739418
https://website.com/media/f/7/e/f7eciw3/normal.jpg 2445741718
```

*Would download as:*

```
2435955711.jpg
2445739418.jpg
2445741718.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to run the following tiny script.

This contains all your URLs:

```
$ cat url_images
https://website.com/media/r/x/3/rx34aw3/normal.jpg
https://website.com/media/q/3/c/q3cciw3/normal.jpg
https://website.com/media/f/7/e/f7eciw3/normal.jpg
```

This will create a for loop for every line in the url_images file and generate the name based on the URL name.

```
URL: https://website.com/media/r/x/3/rx34aw3/normal.jpg
File name: website.com_media_r_x_3_rx34aw3_normal.jpg

$ for URL in $(cat url_images); do xFNAME="$(echo $URL | sed 's/^https*:\/\///' | tr '/' '_')"; curl $URL -o $xFNAME; done
```

At the end you will have these files:

```
website.com_media_q_3_c_q3cciw3_normal.jpg
website.com_media_f_7_e_f7eciw3_normal.jpg
website.com_media_r_x_3_rx34aw3_normal.jpg
```